Mongo Atlas Search find by one of two fields
I have a documents in collections like:
{
_id:"....",
resourceId: "375749d7-a828-4a7b-acc0-77539fbcb7b4" // string type
name: "bla random word"
}

with index:
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "type": "autocomplete"
      },
      "resourceId": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

I have a golang api to find it
I want to search a term that contains exact in name OR in resourceId
for example if I find a partial name like "bla" returns documents with this name, if I find some words contains all of the words like "bla random"
In another hand, if I find by an id like "375749d7-a828-4a7b-acc0-77539fbcb7b4" or partially "375749d7" returns the documents that resourceId contains this term
I'm not sure that index is ok and I try to use this code
mustClauses := bson.A{
        bson.D{
            {Key: "$or", Value: bson.A{
                bson.D{
                    {Key: "autocomplete", Value: bson.D{
                        {Key: "path", Value: "name"},
                        {Key: "query", Value: searchTerm},
                    }},
                },
                bson.D{
                    {Key: "regex", Value: bson.D{
                        {Key: "path", Value: "resourceId"},
                        {Key: "query", Value: searchTerm},
                        {Key: "allowAnalyzedField", Value: true},
                    }},
                },
            }},
        },
    }


    search := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$search", Value: bson.M{
                "index": index,
                "compound": bson.M{
                    "must":   mustClauses,
                },
            },
        },
    }

but must cannot contains $or, should contains autocomple, regex, etc
In another hand I try to use should but returns inconsistent documents (if you search "bla random" return documents that only contains "bla", etc)
Any knows how to implement this?

Would it be simpler to do 2 substring search through $regexMatch like this?

is not possible, as a requirement of the project we need to use mongo search, but thank's for the reply :)

After I seek solutions I see a solution, the index it's fine but the golang code should be changed
func buildSearch(locale string, searchTerm string, index string) bson.D {
    var arrayFilter = addLocaleFilter(locale)
    addTextFilters(&arrayFilter, searchTerm)

    search := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$search", Value: bson.M{
                "index": index,
                "compound": bson.M{
                    "must": arrayFilter,
                },
                "count": bson.D{
                    {Key: "type", Value: "total"},
                },
            },
        },
    }

    return search
}

func addTextFilters(arrayFilter *bson.A, text string) {
    if text != "" {
        textFilters :=
            bson.A{
                addAutocompleteFilterWithBoost(text, "name", NameScore),
                addTextFilterWithBoost(text, "resourceId", ResourceIdScore),
            }

        *arrayFilter = append(*arrayFilter, bson.D{
            {Key: "compound",
                Value: bson.M{
                    "should": textFilters,
                },
            },
        })
    }
}

func addTextFilterWithBoost(term string, path string, score int) bson.D {
    return bson.D{
        {Key: "text", Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "path", Value: bson.A{path}},
            {Key: "query", Value: term},
            {Key: "score", Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "boost", Value: bson.D{
                    {Key: "value", Value: score},
                }},
            }},
        }},
    }
}

func addAutocompleteFilterWithBoost(term string, path string, score int) bson.D {
    return bson.D{
        {Key: "autocomplete", Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "path", Value: path},
            {Key: "query", Value: term},
            {Key: "score", Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "boost", Value: bson.D{
                    {Key: "value", Value: score},
                }},
            }},
        }},
    }
}

